# How can I pass variable from one controller to another? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have controller with action (welcome#index):

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @card = current_user.cards.review_before(Date.today).first
    @my_test_variable #this variable from another controller
  end
end
```

and I have another controller:

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController

    def review
    if @card.check = true
      @my_test_variable = 1
    else
      @my_test_variable = 2
    end
    redirect_to root_path #redirect to welcome#index 
  end
end
```

How can I put @my_test_variable value to action index controller Welcome to use it in view index?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're asking is how to make them available to the next request.  Put them in the session:

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  def review
    if @card.check = true
      session[:my_test_variable] = 1
    else
      session[:my_test_variable] = 2
    end
    redirect_to root_path #redirect to welcome#index 
  end
end

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @card = current_user.cards.review_before(Date.today).first
    session[:my_test_variable]    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I will not question why you would want to do this but one solution is redirect to root_path with a parameter and then grab it in the other controller:

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
    def review
    if @card.check == true
      @my_test_variable = 1
    else
      @my_test_variable = 2
    end
    redirect_to root_path(my_test_variable: @my_test_variable)
  end
end

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @card = current_user.cards.review_before(Date.today).first
    @my_test_variable = params[:my_test_variable] # will be a string
  end
end
```

(and btw, you have a typo in the if statement. should be ==, not =)

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be making the variable global so that it can be assessed from any controller and later making it null.

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController

 def index

    $count = 125
  end

end

class PaymentController < ApplicationController

  def price

    puts $count
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The login in the cards controller should probably be in the model, then you don't have to worry about the approach you have taken.

It is highly uncommon to have 2 controller instances involved with processing one request.